# Spring exception while creating Vaadin component: 'There is no UI available. UI scope is not active.'

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I am quites new to spring boot and Vaadin respectively it is quite some time since I worked with it.
The application was restructured to a multi module project. The former Vaadin spring-boot project was splitted into modules foo-application, foo-data, foo-business and foo-ui.

The application module consists from the entry point main method of Application.java and the application properties. Vaadin version used is 23.3.2 and spring boot 2.7.7.

@Route annotation for root is a start view which redirects to another view.
The bean discovery and management seems to work well, application is annotated like this:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.example.foo.data.entitiy" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.foo"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.example.foo.data.repository" })
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableVaadin("com.example.foo")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The MainLayout looks like this:

```
@RolesAllowed("Admin")
@Theme(value = "my_theme")
@PWA(name = "Foo App", shortName = "Foo", offlineResources = { "icons/Logo-square.png" })
@NpmPackage(value = "line-awesome", version = "1.3.0")
@NpmPackage(value = "@vaadin-component-factory/vcf-nav", version = "1.0.6")
public class MainLayout extends AppLayout implements AppShellConfigurator {

    private BreadCrumb breadCrumb;
    private VersionInfo versionInfo;

    public MainLayout(BreadCrumb breadCrumb, VersionInfo versionInfo, SecurityService securityService) {
        this.breadCrumb = breadCrumb;
        this.versionInfo = versionInfo;

        buildLayout();
    } ...
```

The two Components BreadCrumb and VersionInfo are UI scoped, when I run the application everything I get an Exception:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.foo.ui.views.main.MainLayout': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'breadCrumb': Scope 'vaadin-ui' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no UI available. The UI scope is not active
com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'de.datagroup.csdb.ui.views.main.MainLayout': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'breadCrumb': Scope 'vaadin-ui' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no UI available. The UI scope is not active
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleExceptionDuringRequest(VaadinService.java:1613)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1576)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:369)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:106)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
```

The component looks like this:

```
@UIScope    
@SpringComponent
public class VersionInfo extends VerticalLayout {
...
}
```

It seems the component is initialized way too early because the Vaadin Session or the UI is not ready and available yet. The error comes right away befoere the user even has logged in. Spring security is used for authentication and authorisation.

Any idea, how I can prevent this. If I yust remove the UIScope then the application starts as expected but then other exceptions are thrown that points that components are used with the wrong scope.

Thanks and regards
Matt

Comment: What spring beans are you using in the MainLayout? What's BreadCrumb ?

Comment: BreadCrumb is a navigation component which displays the application path. BreadCrumb, VersionInfo and the SecurityService (Service) are injected via constructor.

Comment: And BreadCrumb has UIScope?

Comment: Yes it has UIScope and creates some RouterLink s for the navigation.

Comment: Why is it UIScope?

Comment: I do not know I am only restructuring the project. I have not origionally developed it. If I remove the UIScope the app starts like expected, but if I reload switch language I get an error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move a node from one state tree to another. If this is intentional, first remove the node from its current state tree by calling removeFromTree so I guess it is needed there.

Comment: I refactored the App now and created the components myself in the MainLayout. Now it is working as expected.

Comment: How are instances of MainLayout created? (Or rather "were" now that you refactored it.)